# How to suspend all Argo cronjobs using Argo Workflows CLI?

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows

Hi I often run into situations where I'm required to pause all the jobs using Argo Workflows CLI.

However I cannot find it in the official documentation to do so. [Official Link](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/cli/argo_cron_suspend/)

Is there a way to acheive this?
NOTE: We cannot do the same using the web UI also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pause all the cron jobs by using the below ssh command with argo cli

```
argo cron list -o name | awk '{print "argo cron suspend "$1}' | bash
```